# Displaying random rows without repetition

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

My issues are:

1. How to display random ads, so the same ad wont appear again.
2. How to give importance to the ad with higher credit value.

Sql Server DB Table

```
AdId AdName AdUrl     Credits
 1    Ad1    abc.com   10
 2    Ad2    def.com   40
 3    Ad3    fgi.com   30
 4    Ad4    xyz.com   10
```

The above ads table may contain 1000's of records. I want to show 10 ads at a time (by giving importance to credits having higher value).

**My Approach**

1. What I am doing currently is selecting 10 random ads from the ads table  and displaying them.
2. Also added a flag IsAdDisplayed (boolean) to the ads table, so that the same random ad wont repeat (until it displays all the ads)
3. when I am done showing all the ads, I am updating IsAdDisplayed back again to false.

**LINQ**

```
var result = (from u in idb.ads
      select u).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);
```

But this will not take the higher credits in to consideration.

Is it the right approach? How display the random ads (with credits taken into account) and that the same ads wont repeat displaying?

Comment: Instead of picking a random and set a boolean flag I would shuffle the list and then iterate through the shuffled list.

Comment: No matter what effect the credits will have on the first random sorting: If there are 1000 records, a higher-valued ad will appear again after at least 100 queries like any other.

Comment: I would use HashSet or unique container

Comment: Something like this can work only if you have one user, otherwise you'll need information about what ads have been saw by the current user. You don't need to update the database but have cookies and request the ads excluding those who are marked as saw into current cookie.

Comment: Sort the ads by 'credit' with the highest credit at the top, then select an ad at random at position 0 to length-1.  when you choose an ad, just remove it from the list so it can't be chosen again.  Here's the tricky bit, how do you skew your random number to be more likely to be at the start of the list?  There are various ways of selecting a random number 1 - N such that the lower numbers are more likely to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication100
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("AdId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("AdName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AdUrl", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Credits", typeof (int));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "Ad1", "abc.com", 10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "Ad2", "def.com", 40});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "Ad3", "fgi.com", 30});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4, "Ad4", "xyz.com", 40});

            Random rand = new Random();
            List<DataRow> randomRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { row = x, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.row).ToList();
            DataTable dt2 = randomRows.CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time 10 ads will be loaded on every request user makes, so is there any way to deal with directly ads table, instead of copying to dt2?

Comment: You do not need the last line.  I just added so you can see results if needed.  Just use the List.

Answer (score 0):

> How display the random ads (with credits taken into account) and that
>   the same ads wont repeat displaying?

If you want to give priority to credits, you can try to write query something like following (You might required to convert it into LINQ).

Here record having more credit will get more priority. Like `credit > 80` will get the highest priority and `credit < 40` will get the least priority.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 80 * 
                FROM   [table] 
                WHERE  credit > 80 
                ORDER  BY Newid())A 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 60 * 
                FROM   [table] 
                WHERE  credit <= 80 
                       AND credit > 60 
                ORDER  BY Newid())B 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 40 * 
                FROM   [table] 
                WHERE  credit <= 60 
                       AND credit > 40 
                ORDER  BY Newid())C 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 20 * 
                FROM   [table] 
                WHERE  credit <= 40 
                ORDER  BY Newid())D) T 
ORDER  BY Newid()
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> by giving importance to credits having higher value

Does that mean that as long as you have non-shown ads with credit 40, you don't want to show ads with credit 10 at all? Or do you mean that you want to give ads with higher credits a higher chance to be shown. And if so: if credits are 4 time higher, should the chance to be shown be four time bigger?

Let's assume that you don't want to show ads with lower credits as long as you have non-shown ads with higher credits.

```
int nrOfAdsToSelect = ...;
var selectedAds = dbContext.Adds
    .Where(ad => !ad.IsSelected)
    .OrderyDescending(ad => ad.Credit)
    .Take(nrOfAddsToSelect);
```

However, if you want to give all ads a chance to be shown, only ads with higher credits a higher chance, you should think about how much higher chance.

The easiest would be to translate the credit into a range of integers, indicating when the ad should be selected:

```
Id Credit  => Range
00    01      00
01    01      01
02    02      02, 03                                    // credit 2: 2 numbers
03    03      04, 05, 06                                // credit 3: 3 numbers
04    10      07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16    // 10 numbers
```

Take a random number in range [00, 16]. The chance that Id 04 is chosen is 10 times higher than the chance that Id 01 is chosen.

So you need a function to create an integer range from a Credit and a StartNumber. This can be as simple as above, it can be any other algorithm, depending on how much you rate chances of ads with higher credits.

You can use your credit-to-range function to convert a sequence of non-displayed Adds to the sequence of integer numbers.

As extension functions:

```
static IEnumerable<int> ToRange(this int credit, int startNumber)
{
     // example: Credit 40 is 40 times more chance than credit 1.
     // so range length is equal to credit
     return Enumerable.Range(startNumber, credit);
}

static IEnumerable<int> ToRange(this IEnumerable<Ad> adds)
{
    int startNumber = 0;
    foreach (Ad add in adds)
    {
        // only use ads that are not displayed yet to select a new Ad.
        if (!ad.IsDisplayed)
        {
             var range = add.Credit.ToRange();
             foreach (var value in range) yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Ad> ads = ...
var range = ads.ToRange().ToList();
int selectedIndex = rnd.Next(range.Count);
var firstSelectedAdd = ads[selectedIndex];
```

The problem is, that as soon as you selected your first ad, the chances of your 2nd ad should change. You'll need to create a new range:

```
static Ad Select(this IReadOnlyList<Ad> ads)
{
    var range = ads.ToRange().ToList();
    int selectedIndex = rnd.Next(range.Count);
    return ads[selectedIndex];
}

static IEnumerable<Ad> SelectAds(this IEnumerable<Ad> ads, int selectCount)
{
    for (int i=0; i<selectCount; ++i)
    {
        var selectedAd = ads.Select();
        yield return selectedAd;
        selectedAd.IsDisplayed = true; // to make sure it is not selected again
    }
}
```